# Sharepoint 2013 Global navigation issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, branding, sharepoint-branding

I am trying to set Global navigation for my publishing portal site in sharepoint 2013 using Managed Metadata. It works fine for Default.aspx but when I browse to Site Settings page it does not show some of navigations.

My navigation is shown bellow :
[image]

Now when I browse to default Page it shows navigation perfectly as shown bellow.
[image]

But when I browse to Site Settings page it only shows :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: I have created Top Navigation using Managed Metada Service in Sharepoint 2013. It works fine for all pages such as Home.aspx, default.aspx etc... In other words it works great with WebPart Pages. But when I navigate to any of Application pages e.g. Site Settings or Site Columns( they are called application pages which by default referencing default.master page.), it is not showing my Top Nav bar with all its menu item as well as Sub menu items.

I have googled lot, finally I got solution for SharePoint 2010 from here,
First locate/find PlaceHolderTopNavBar

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar"
```

and rename it to PlaceHolderTopNavBarOriginal,
I looked into my custom.html page for same div tag as suggested in link above but I could not. After that I find

```
<div class="ms-hide">
```

and put

```
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
```

inside that div.

I have written blog here:
http://apppagetopnavigation.blogspot.in/

Hopefully this will help you all.

Comment: Thanks kleopatra. Will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure. But I think that's caused by the fact that they're using different masterpages.

Meaning when the person that activated the cascading dropdowns forgot to make that master page the default for the site. He might have only selected set as custom master page instead of default.

Sean

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug it happens in all SharePoint 2013 versions and also in the Office 365, in the settings pages it will always show just one level in the menu.

Comment: Hi Joao this is not a bug. I think we need to set Global navigation for Settings pages. As Setting pages are system pages. They have different global navigation hierarchy. So we need to overwrite our global navigation with default global navigation.